# Understanding Upper Side Band (USB) and Lower Side Band (LSB) of Modulated signal

Tags: waves, signal-processing

[image]

I want to know that what is **UPPER SIDE BAND** and **LOWER SIDE BAND** in this picture?

I have a confusion that the portion **above the x axis is the USB** and **the portion below the x axis is LSB**. I have doubt that I am thinking it in the right way.

Am I thinking it correctly ?

Comment: This is a time-domain diagram. The sidebands show up in the frequency spectrum. Do you know about Fourier transforms?

Comment: Yes a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Am I thinking it correctly ?*
No, although there is information about the USB and LSB in your graph you have not interpreted correctly.

The graph is a graph of voltage against time for an amplitude modulated signal.
If consists of a signal which is called the carrier wave, $v_{\rm c}(t) = V_{\rm c} \sin(2 \pi f_{\rm c} t)$ of frequency $f_{\rm c}$  and a message signal, $v_{\rm m}(t) = V_{\rm m} \cos\left(2\pi f_m t\right)$ of frequency $f_{\rm m}$ with $f_{\rm c}\gg f_{\rm m}$.

When these two are combined by a process called modulation the resulting voltage is of the form,

$V_{\rm am}(t) = A \sin(2\pi f_c t) + B\sin\left(2\pi \left[f_c + f_m\right] t\right) + B\sin\left(2\pi \left[f_c - f_m\right] t\right)$

which you will note is the sum of,

the carrier, $A \sin(2\pi f_c t)$, of frequency $f_{\rm c}$

the upper side band, $B\sin\left(2\pi \left[f_c + f_m\right] t\right)$, of frequency $f_{\rm c}+f_{\rm m}$

the lower side band, $B\sin\left(2\pi \left[f_c - f_m\right] t\right)$, of frequency $f_{\rm c}-f_{\rm m}$

So the side bands are the voltages above and below the carrier frequency which appear as the result of the modulation process.

[image]

From your diagram you can estimate the various frequencies as $f_{\rm c} = \frac{1}{T_{\rm c}}$ and $f_{\rm m} = \frac{1}{T_{\rm m}}$.

Often you will find the information about sidebands presented in the form of an amplitude against frequency graph as shown below.

[image]